# How do I expand stack traces in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4

XCode 4 has a really stupid feature that "summarizes" stack traces in the debugger by showing the first and last two items in the call stack. Does anyone know how to eliminate the dotted line and show the useful information?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to see the entire stack trace, drag the slider at the bottom left of the debug navigator (below the stack traces) all the way to the right.

It's not simply showing the first two and the last one, though. Rather, it's showing the top and bottom of the stack, as well as any code that comes from your application. The assumption is that you often don't care about the internals of system frameworks. You can adjust the slider to get varying levels of detail.